# How do I log an R session to a file?

Tags: r, logging, stata

Other than through redirection, which captures an entire session, is there a way to start and stop logging during an R session?  To clarify, I am looking for something similar to the `log using` command in Stata.

Comment: I also think this is the dumbest question ever posted, but there isn't a "dumb-question" tag.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do you know about `sink()` in base R ?

There are also some logging packages on CRAN: [logging](http://cran.r-project.org/package=logging), [log4r](http://cran.r-project.org/package=log4r) and possibly more.

Lastly, Emacs user have ESS and its transcript mode. You can save your session as a log, and in general, the 'work from file and execute from the file' approach builds a (partial, commands-only) log as you work.

Comment: sink() was exactly what I was looking for, but completely unintuitively named.  As I said in my comment, I know this is dumb.  Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

For the sake of completing the answer using sink

```
# copy the log to a text file
sink("./logofcode.txt")
Your R code(s) goes here
you can use a stored R code as well using source()
source("./XS_SPEC_CF.R",echo=T, max.deparse.length=1e3)
sink()
```

Comment: Since I need to do this quite often, I converted usct01's approach into a tiny function:

    `source_with_log <- function(r_script, log_file) {
      sink(file = log_file)
      source(r_script, echo = TRUE)
      sink()
    }`

Answer (score 5):

There's `savehistory(file)` which will write the entire history as plaintext, or, if you're trying to log output, use `sink(file, split = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a package called [logr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=logr) that allows you a lot of control over what and when things get logged, but is much easier to use than `sink()`.  Here is an example:

```
library(logr)

# Open the log
log_open("mytest.log")

# Print text to the log
log_print("Here is a test log statement")

# Print a dataframe to the log
log_print(mtcars)

# Close the log
log_close()
```

And here is the generated log:

```
========================================================================= 
Log Path: ./log/mytest.log 
Working Directory: C:/packages/Testing/VS 
User Name: User 
R Version: 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) 
Machine: BOSAK-HOME x86-64 
Operating System: Windows 10 x64 build 18363 
Log Start Time: 2021-01-24 21:13:55 
========================================================================= 

Here is a test log statement 

NOTE: Log Print Time:  2021-01-24 21:13:56 
NOTE: Elapsed Time in seconds: 1.07599902153015 

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

NOTE: Data frame has 32 rows and 11 columns. 

NOTE: Log Print Time:  2021-01-24 21:13:57 
NOTE: Elapsed Time in seconds: 0.795979976654053 

========================================================================= 
Log End Time: 2021-01-24 21:14:06 
Log Elapsed Time: 0 00:00:10 
=========================================================================
```

Comment: Noting it's been 8 years since the original question (!!), I did recently learn of `logr`, but had never seen it in action.  I recently fell hard for `spdlog` for spewing information in both C++ and Python.  Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `sink` function you might also look at the `txtStart` and related functions in the `TeachingDemos` package or the similar functionality in the `R2HTML` package (which came first).