# Get all R code which is run when running

Tags: r, try-catch, eval

Suppose I have a bunch of R code in a script and I want to log all the R code which is run from the .GlobalEnv to a flat file or a database together with the errors and warning messages.
I could write a simple logme function as follows or make it a bit more complex to also fetch the errors by changing `options(error = mylogginfunction)`

```
mylogfile <- tempfile()
logme <- function(x){
  mode <- "at"
  if(!file.exists(mylogfile)){
    mode <- "wt"
  }
  myconn <- file(mylogfile, mode)
  writeLines(x, myconn)
  close(myconn)
  invisible()
}

logme(sprintf("%s: started some yadayada, ", Sys.time()))
x <- 10
x * 7
logme(sprintf("%s: done with yadayada", Sys.time()))

## Get the log
cat(readLines(mylogfile))
```

The log prints out: 
*2015-05-14 17:24:31: started some yadayada,  2015-05-14 17:24:31: done with yadayada*

But what I would like to have is that the logfile writes down the expressions which were executed without me having to write a wrapper around each statement.
I would like the log to look like.
*2015-05-14 17:24:31: started some yadayada,* **x <- 10, x * 7** *2015-05-14 17:24:31: done with yadayada*

So my question is, how do I fetch what is being executed by R so that I can store the executed expressions in a log/database. And without having to write a function call before each expression (as in myhandler(x <- 10); myhandler(x * 10)). 
Any help on this?

Comment: The `R CMD BATCH filename.R` command line produces a `.Rout` file with what seems you are asking.

Comment: I'm not interested in the .Rout or what is piped by Rscript myscript > mylog.log. I'm interested in the expressions.

Comment: The `R CMD BATCH` writes also the expressions. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried R CMD BATCH. But I need the expressions which are run so that I can store them in a logging database 1 by 1 as they are run by the R intepreter.

Comment: I don't think to really get it. However, what about writing another `.R` file that reads line by line your input file, write the command somewhere (through `cat` or saving the expression on a db), execute it (through `eval(parse(text=))`) and goes on to the next line?

Comment: Thats a way to go which I also had in mind but my question was more to have the running expressions in the same process available as where the R commands are run.

Comment: Use `sink`? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9636800/1412059) mentions some packages that might also be helpful.

Comment: How would sink help me to get the R expressions which are run? sink diverts R **output** to a connection.

Comment: Are you looking for Sweave or knitr then?

Comment: Yes, but without having to type Sweave or knit.

Answer (score 4):

For catching input commands you could use `addTaskCallback`

```
mylogfile <- tempfile()
addTaskCallback(
    function(...) { 
        expr <- deparse(as.expression(...)[[1]]) # it could handled better...
        cat(expr, file=mylogfile, append=TRUE, sep="\n")
        # or cat(sprintf("[%s] %s", Sys.time(), expr),...) if you want timestamps
        TRUE
    }
    ,name="logger"
)

x <- 10
x * 7

removeTaskCallback("logger")
```

Then result is:

```
cat(readLines(mylogfile), sep="\n")
... addTaskCallback definition ...
x <- 10
x * 7
```

But what you get is **parsed** expression, which means that line

```
x+1;b<-7;b==2
```

will be logged as

```
x + 1
b <- 7
b == 2
```

In addition:

- output will not be logged, in particular `message` or `warning` shown in console
- in case of `error` logging will not be triggered, so you need separate function to handle it

Answer (score 0):

This is probably to simple to work in every case, but you can try with this:

Define myhandler as:

```
myhandler <- function(x, file = stdout()) {
  expr <- substitute(x)
  for(e_line in as.list(expr)) {
    cat( file = file, as.character(Sys.time()), capture.output(e_line), "\n")
    eval(e_line, envir = parent.frame())
  }
}
```

Use it with your code inside the brackets:

```
myhandler({

  a <- 1
  a <- a + 1
  print(a)

})
```

Result:

```
# 2015-05-14 18:46:34 `{` 
# 2015-05-14 18:46:34 a <- 1 
# 2015-05-14 18:46:34 a <- a + 1 
# 2015-05-14 18:46:34 print(a) 
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's close to what I had in mind, but I tried to exclude this answer explicitely in my question where it states 'without having to write a function call before each expression'. And this solution just puts all the expressions in 1 block. I'm looking for a solution where I don't need the myhandler before all the code.

Answer (score 0):

I confess that I don't really get what "to have the running expressions in the same process available as where the R commands are run" means when we chatted a bit in the comments. However, I expanded what I had in mind. You can create a `logGenerator.R` file with the following lines:

```
logGenerator<-function(sourcefile,log) {
  ..zz <- file(log, open = "at")
  sink(..zz)
  sink(..zz, type = "message")
  on.exit({
    sink(type="message")
    sink()
    close(..zz)
  })
  ..x<-parse(sourcefile)
  for (..i in 1:length(..x)) {
    cat(as.character(Sys.time()),"\n")
    cat(as.character(..x[..i]),"\n")
    ..y<-eval(..x[..i])
  }
}
```

This function takes as arguments the source file and the log file names. This script will take an R file and will log the time at which each instruction is executed. Then it records the expression on the same log file. Every output directed to the `stdout()` and the error messages are directed to the log file. You obviously don't have to modify in any way your source file.

Comment: Nicola, thanks for the answer. It's the same as given by bergant basically. I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to pass a sourcefile. Is this possible?

Comment: How do you think you pass the expressions you want to evaluate and store if not in a sourcefile? Sorry for the answer, but I don't think I really get your constraints and what is your workflow.

Comment: The workflow is 
`logme(sprintf("%s: started some yadayada, ", Sys.time()))
x <- 10
x * 7
logme(sprintf("%s: done with yadayada", Sys.time()))
`
Which should result a log file stating '2015-05-14 17:24:31: started some yadayada, x <- 10, x * 7 2015-05-14 17:24:31: done with yadayada'

Comment: I'm not being clear. What do you mean by "I don't need to pass a sourcefile"?  I guess my function produces the output you are asking.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to write logGenerator('myRscript.R', 'mylog.log') but only `logme("mylog.log") and next logme(sprintf("%s: started some yadayada, ", Sys.time()))
x <- 10
x * 7
logme(sprintf("%s: done with yadayada", Sys.time()))` which generates the desired output of the question. So no wrapper around my code.